# How to make text area to be height of 10 rows fixed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How to make text area to be height of 10 rows fixed ?
I put like

```
<label for="textarea" style="font-weight: bold;">Message Content:</label>
<br/>
<textarea cols="40" rows="10" class="ui-input-text" name="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
```

but it is not 10 rows height when page loads and it is resizable.

Answer (score 9):

It is only resizable in browsers that allow it to be resized. You can prevent it with this CSS:

```
textarea
{
    resize: none;
}
```

Whereas regarding the height not being 10 rows, I suspect that it is because the 10 row height is calculated for the original style and if you've changed the style to a different font and/or font-size, and added padding, it may not match. Try setting the height to, say, `10em` or `10em` + padding.

Answer (score 7):

With `resize: none;`

If the height is not right, maybe try to set it with CSS

```
<textarea style="resize: none;" cols="40" rows="10" ...
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try:

```
resize:none;
height: 320px;
max-height: 320px;
```

works for me